# Replicate scipy rankdata in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I cannot figure out a clean solution on how to retrieve the new indices of the sorted array in MATLAB.
Scipy (in Python) has `rankdata` which I need, while MATLAB's `sort` provides indices.

For example `[0 -3 -1 1]` array after sorting in ascending order is `[-3 -1 0 1]`.

I want to retrieve the new indices, i.e. `[3 1 2 4]`, while MATLAB offers no built in solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
x       = [0 -3 -1 1];
[~,ind] = sort(x);
ind     = ind(ind)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) happens to sort as well ascending, and gives indices both ways.

```
A = [0 -3 -1 1];
[B,I,C] = unique(A);
B =
    -3    -1     0     1
C =
     3
     1
     2
     4
```

Do note that if `A` contains repetitions (unlike your example), this method will fail:

```
A = [0 -3 -1 1 1];
[B,I,C] = unique(A);
B =
    -3    -1     0     1
C =
     3
     1
     2
     4
     4
```

Comment: The best solution if `A` does not contains any repetition.

Comment: @obchardon thanks. I added a note about repetitions. OP's example doesn't have any, hence I used `unique`

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting what you are asking for correctly I think this should work.

```
x = [0 -3 -1 1];
[s,r]=sort(x);
[~,rank] = sort(r);
```

The output I get is

```
s = -3 -1 0 1
rank = 3 1 2 4
```